# Does OpenGL display list bake glVertex data?

Tags: c++, opengl, obsolete, displaylist

I've been using OpenGL in simple immediate mode for a while, and am trying to pass on to retained mode with display lists (which I sadly learned has been deprecated a while). What I would like to know, is when I type:

```
glNewList(list, GL_COMPILE);
glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN);
    glVertex2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        glVertex2f(radius * cos(i * 2.0f * PI / 9.0f), radius * sin(i * 2.0f * PI / 9.0f));
    }
glEnd();
glEndList();
```

does OpenGL precalculate all the 10 vertices in for loop and send them to graphics card baked, like:

```
glVertex2f(0.5f, 0.0f);
glVertex2f(0.499f, 0.0055f);
//so and so forth 10 times...
```

or does it try to do the for loop (and many sin / cos operations) all over for each frame? In other words, is it reasonable to store such a round shape in display lists (and do the rest with glTranslatef, glRotatef, etc...) to avoid trigonometric operations in each frame update, or is there no performance gain at all?

Edit: To avoid a confusion, I intend to create this display list once using the for loop, and then call it by *glCallList(list)* in each frame update (i.e. *glutDisplayFunc()*). I do not create a list for each and every frame.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I didn't read carefully. Forget it ;) The answer is:loop and associated sin/cos runs only once. When and how display list data is stored and when it gets to GPU is implementation-specific. Another thing is that it's completely irrelevant. Display lists are so slow, no sines or cosines will ever get even close. You should pick OpenGL 3+ book/tutorial directly. No need to learn and tweak obsolete stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only the GL command sequence and parameters are "baked" into the display list.  Otherwise OpenGL would have to use some sort of terrifying [`longjmp()`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setjmp.h) monstrosity to re-execute (along with the *complete* process state at that point!) the code between `glNewList()`/`glEndList()`.

Answer (score 5):

Display lists (and the immediate mode rendering it is provided for) are ancient deprecated functionality and the underlying mechanics were up to the driver, some may back it into a draw arrays call while others would just replay the calls with the parameters it got, non of your code is actually re-executed.

Instead you should do the baking explicitly by putting the data into a VBO and use `glDrawArrays`.